# Set select input value via Angular FromControl value

Tags: angular, forms

Can anyone tell me how I can set the initial value of the below select? I have tried doing this through my formControl and although the value in the form will be correct it is not reflected within the view

HTML :

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select name="animationType" formControlName="animationType" 
  placeholder="select animation">

  <mat-option *ngFor="let type of animationTypes" [value]="type">
   {{type.name}}
  </mat-option>

 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS :

```
  animationTypes = [
    { name: 'balloon' },
    { name: 'kite' },
    { name: 'wolf' }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the only solution I found was to plug an ngModel on the select like so.

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select name="animationType" formControlName="animationType" 
  placeholder="select animation" [(ngModel)]="selectedAnimType">

  <mat-option *ngFor="let type of animationTypes" [value]="type.name">
   {{type.name}}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
 <mat-error *ngIf="poemForm.controls.animationType.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()} 
 </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have used `formControlName`, So You can set default value directly from `TS` file like following :

HTML :

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select name="animationType" formControlName="animationType" placeholder="select animation">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let type of animationTypes" [value]="type">
            {{type.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="poemForm.controls.animationType.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.poemForm.patchValue({ 
      animationType: selectedAnimationType // Selected Value E.g. this.animationTypes[0]
    });
  }
```

Comment: this updates the formControl value but in the view the select input still displays the placeholder as if it has no value yet and nothing has been selected. What I need is for the select input to display the value that has been set in the formControl,

Comment: You are using `[value]="type"` as object. So in `selectedAnimationType` you will need to add object only. Like `this.animationTypes[0]`

Comment: Or try using `[value]="type.value"` and use `selectedAnimationType = {some string value existing in array object}`. I think this is the issue.

Comment: neither of these worked, I think you maybe correct that is has something to do with the fact that [value]="type" is an object (i updated the original post with my objects) but I also made selectedAnimationType an object like this { name: "some string" } to match the orginal objects being passed into the ngFor loop but it still did not update the select in the view